# AngularJS - How do I insert compiled HTML into my directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm pretty sure I'm doing this the wrong way, so any help would be appreciated...

Given the following plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/hCjTdt8XmlVPKGgzvgFu?p=preview

I'm trying to compile some Html and insert it in a specific location in my template.  However, I'm getting an error:

```
Can't interpolate: My Value: {{innerHtml}}
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

I'm pretty sure this is because I'm attempting to insert the entire element as Html, but I'm not sure how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Plunker code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
      <test-directive></test-directive>
    </div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller("TestCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myValue = "Hello, World!";
      }]);

      app.directive('testDirective', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: "<h1>Title</h1>My Value: {{innerHtml}}",
          link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.innerHtml = $compile("<input type='text' ng-model='myValue' />")(scope);
          }
        }
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be confused by trying to access innerHtml on your scope? I think you need to be accessing your element to insert DOM. The element will be basically whatever's in your template, but already compiled (link happens after compile). So you can compile and add it to your element.

Try this:

```
element.append($compile("<input type='text' ng-model='myValue' />")(scope));
```

instead of `scope.innerHtml` line. Working in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/z3k6BPVNcNxi6d4XBfXX?p=preview